# How do I access all of my input from my loop so I can store it as an object?

Tags: java, loops, object, arraylist, java-11

I am reading a small file (using Java scanner), parsing the lines into specific strings, and storing the information from the strings into an object. I can only access the last element, but when I move my new object declaration and try to add something from inside the loop, it messes up my code and I don't get anything at all. There are several different loops I need to go through to get all of the information, but I'm only getting the last one. We're only supposed to scan once, I thought.

I added a count thinking I could add another loop (after) but would it even access the same information?

But how do I get all of my objects so I can add them to my arrayList?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
         // read in the song file and build the songs array
        File text = new File ("short.txt");
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner (text);
        
        String artist = " ";
        String title = " ";
        String lyrics = " ";
        
        int count =0; 
        ArrayList <Song> song_list = new ArrayList<Song>();
        
        
        while (scnr.hasNextLine()){
            String next = scnr.nextLine();
            
            
            if (next.startsWith("ARTIST")){
                artist = (next.substring(8, next.length()-1));
                
            }
            else if (next.startsWith("TITLE")) {
                title = (next.substring(7, next.length()-1));
                count++;
            }
            else if (next.startsWith("LYRICS")) {
                lyrics = (next.substring(8, next.length())+"\n");
            }
                if (!next.contains("\"")){
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    lyrics += sb.append(next) + "\n";
                }
            }
        
        Song songs = new Song (artist, title, lyrics);
        song_list.add(songs);
        System.out.print(songs);
        
        
        scnr.close();
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: @ScaryWombat it is outside of the brackets... would you declare it before the loop anyway?

Comment: Is the file always in order? `ARTISTS`, `TITLE` `LYRICS` ?

Comment: @ScaryWombat yes it is! a single double quote on its own line separates lyrics from the next artist.

Comment: Can you include a sample input file with the question? It would be much easier to give an answer with that along with improvements which can be done to the code.

Answer (score 0):

If the files is always in order, you could change your code to test if `lyrics` if not empty, and then insert into your list

```
while (...) {
   // read artists
   // read title
   // read lyrics

   if (!lyrics.isEmpty()) {
       // create song and add to list
       // then reset lyrics to empty
   }
}
```